# How do I draw borders around a matplotlib plot using object-oriented code?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like generate a plot with the coordinate axes in the middle of the plot area.  Using matplotlib, I've managed to get as far as is shown in this sample code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xvalues = [-3,-2,-1,1,2,3]
yvalues = [2,4,-2,-4,1,-1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.scatter(xvalues, yvalues)
```

The problem with using `set_position()` to move the spines into the middle of the plot area is that this *removes* them as elements of the plot's border.  I'm looking for a way to restore the border lines using object-oriented operations on the `Figure` and `Axes` instances `fig` and `ax`, respectively.

**Please** note that I'm interested in manifestly object-oriented code only: operations on `fig` and `ax`.  This constraint is a part of the question.

I won't accept an answer given in terms of `plt` or equivalent.  I already know how to do that.  I'll accept an answer demonstrating that it isn't possible to draw these border lines using only manifestly object-oriented code before I accept an answer using `plt`.

Comment: There is no difference between "using plt" or not. Under the hood, they all fall back to the same code. This means, if you have a solution "using plt", it can easily be adapted to not use "`plt`" - under the condition that you show such solution. In general, I would think that the easiest is to add an additional axes in the background.

Comment: There is a difference: what I type.  After two weeks of reading matplotlib documentation, I still don't know what to type to use the object-oriented approach.  If it's so easy to adapt, then surely there's project documentation or a tutorial or a guide blog that explains how it's done?  Can you link me to anything, because it's well hidden from me.

Comment: You can give us a command you have and ask how to do it in OOP style or vice versa. What I cannot do here is to write down a complete tutorial.